# CDC support in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, cdc

Is it possible to transfer data from CDC enabled tables in an on-prem SQL Server to Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory? Querying the cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ function doesn't seem to be supported. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions cannot be called from ADF so it is not possible without wrapping the `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes` function in a stored proc or exposing a view.

Answer (score 4):

You could potentially do this, but you'd be re-inventing the wheel, tracking your LSN windows and writing the CDC apply logic.  SSIS has the CDC extract and apply functionality built-in, and you can run SSIS CDC data flows either on your on-prem SQL Server, or in an ADF SSIS runtime.